# VueJS sort/order an array of objects by a specific property

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have an array of contact objects that all of an `isPrimary` property. Only one of them should be true, but regardless I would like to sort any primary contacts to the top of the array.  I'm using VueJS and plan to do this on created in a list component. I know I can create a computed property, but not sure how to use sort when it's not really comparing a and b, but just looking to re-order any that are primary. Here's a rough start:

```
sortedContacts () {
  return this.contacts.sort((a, b) => { // what to do here? })
}
```

Any assistance would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` and Boolean to number type coercion like so:

```
return this.contacts.sort(({ isPrimary: a }, { isPrimary: b }) => b - a);
```

This works by comparing the numeric representations of `true` and `false`, which are `1` and `0` respectively, and based upon the return value of `sort`'s callback, it returns a number which determines the place each item should be moved too.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.contacts.sort((a, b) => { a.isPrimary ? -1 : 1 })
```